# Mixpanel not able to identify users using "alias" or "identify"

Tags: mixpanel

I an developing a chrome extension which doesn't has any sign up or sign in flow, instead depends on authentication of a separate web app. I started integrating mixpanel and tracking user events anonymously, Now i want to identify those anonymous users using "alias" and "identify" api. I have a user_id for identifying users from the web app exposed REST api. Now if i apply a boolean check and make sure i call mixpanel "alias(user_id)" once and call "identify(user_id)" every time user visits a page, I can see a user entry in explore tab of mixpanel but live events tab has a anonymous user with same user_id and its tracked data, I wish to link such anonymous users with appropriate user profiles.

Please help me with this if you have some understanding of mixpanel. I am new at this.

Answer (score 2):

Since I didn't had a sign in or sign up flow, I cannot use 
    mixpanel.alias
Hence i am now calling 
    mixpanel.identify
As soon as user installs the plugin, Since "identify" api can be called any number of times for an user, We are able to track all future events as soon as plugin gets installed.

This way by not letting the user generate anonymous events we can handle such situation.